# Safe to put insulation around recessed light cans after convert to LED?

Tags: insulation, led, recessed-lighting

I have a ranch home, in the kitchen there are recessed lights. I want to replace them with [these LED ones](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Halo-5-in-and-6-in-2700K-Matte-White-Recessed-Retrofit-Baffle-Trim-LED-Module-80-CRI-RL560WH6827/204280491?MERCH=REC-_-piphorizontal2_rr-1-_-203310667-_-204280491-_-N) that home depot sells:

[image]

I took a look at the insulation around the recessed light cans from the attic, and there is none. The cans have holes in them, so my precious warm air is leaking right out of these areas.

After I convert to the LED kits, is it safe to insulate around the cans? I currently have fiberglass bats in the rest of the attic, can I seal the cans with silver tape, then put bats on top?

Thanks

Comment: LEDs can still generate some heat, it really depends on whether the can is IC-rated or not.

Comment: Your idea is reasonable (and reasonably safe). The problem is that someday down the road someone may swap back to old-school flood bulbs, and that could be dangerous.

Comment: Ah yeah good points - ok so probably best to just replace the cans, looks like they make air-tight ones anyway, I don't think I could get air-tight by just doing the insulation myself: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Halo-6-in-Aluminum-Recessed-Lighting-New-Construction-IC-Air-Tite-Housing-H7ICAT/100097046

Comment: Airtight is not the issue, it's being listed to be covered by insulation and still be able to shed heat from the bulb, however their design can do that and still get listed.   All fixtures must be built for the worst case of incandescent bulbs, unless it is impossible-by-design to put one in there.  LEDs need heat removal as much as incandescents, while they make 1/8 the heat, they also dislike running warm, while incandescents love heat.

Comment: Your LED light trim is effectively sealing your living space from your attic. I wouldn't sweat it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to cover your recessed light cans with insulation you need to have IC-rated (Insulation Contact) cans installed regardless of the type of light installed in the can.  Since you mentioned your cans have holes in them, they are most definitely not IC-rated.  You'd have to buy some remodel IC-rated cans and replaced what you have with those before covering with insulation.

[image]

Comment: Some IC-rated cans have plenty of holes. In fact, I have encountered IC and non-IC rated cans which seemed to be physically identical. The only difference was the IC ones had a different label which specified a lower max wattage for the bulb, and possibly had a thermal cutout with a higher setpoint.

Comment: Fine Homebuilding Magazine published a hack using 5 gallon buckets and spray foam - They're typically sticklers for code compliance. Perhaps an oversight on their end? -- https://www.finehomebuilding.com/2020/04/07/effective-can-light-cover

Answer (score 2):

There are IC-rated (Insulation Contact) direct install LED recess lighting, that you can use without the need for a recessed lighting can.

[image: LED driver]

Example item above is found at Lowes (Item # 1500773 Model # HLB6099FS1EMWR)

But you can find IC rated led lighting units from Home Depot, Amazon, Lowes, and many other places. They are very commonly sold units.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! Please provide a proper [reference](/help/referencing) for the image.

Comment: Link for reference (Lowes, Home Depot, Amazon are just a few examples of places you can find them): https://www.lowes.com/pd/Halo-White-LED-Remodel-and-New-Construction-Recessed-Light-Kit-Fits-Opening-6-in/1001772082?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-lit-_-google-_-lia-_-143-_-recessedlighting-_-1001772082-_-0&placeholder=null&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=Cj0KCQjw2tCGBhCLARIsABJGmZ5IBapajRspMF-yVbzulaJ64VyFQ1WyHb84Dduo-DvHroFIO7qVwvoaAhS9EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: I just installed a similar Cooper Lighting HALO 4" LED recessed light fixture that I bought from Lowe's.  They're great.  Mine offered 5 selections on the light color (there's a multi-position switch on the junction box).  Only the 2700K and 3000K colors were suitable for me, the higher temps are too blueish/sterile.  Great to have the choice though.  I also like that these are UL listed and IC rated.  Don't limit yourself to the selection at your hardware store.  Cooper offers lots of different models; see https://www.cooperlighting.com/global/product-list#c=cooper-lighting:brands/halo